# Is there a faster way to make multiple child directories?

Tags: powershell

Using the "mkdir" command, I was led to understand that I could make multiple directories by just adding them, like so:

```
mkdir folder1 folder2 folder3
```

That didn't work.

I solved it by typing "mkdir", then pressing enter, which prompted me:

```
Path[0]: folder1
Path[1]: folder2
etc...
```

Is there a faster way to make multiple child directories in the folder I am currently at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create multiple directories if you pass an array to the [mkdir](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=293886) cmdlet:

```
mkdir folder1, folder2, folder3
```

You could also create an explicit array:

```
mkdir @('folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3')
```

Comment: You should explain that mkdir is function in PowerShell that extends New-Item and that `-Path` works with arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create directories in a shorter way using range notation

```
mkdir folder{1..3}
```

or with any different values

```
mkdir folder{1,two,3,four}
```

it also works with nested dirs

```
mkdir -p parent/folder-{one,two}/sub-folder-{1..3}
```

Happy directories creating! :)